# c++: использование лямбда-функции в качестве параметра

Tags: c++, функции, c++11, lambda

Подскажите как использовать лямбда функцию в качестве параметра метода класса

Есть следующее:

```
class MyClass {

    struct IData {
    };

    using func_t = bool (*) (const MyClass::IData&);
    
    void method(func_t filter = nullptr);
};
```

но вызов

```
object.method([](const MyClass::IData& data) {return true;});
```

приводит к ошибке

> Error (active)    E0413   no suitable conversion function from "lambda
> []bool (MyClass::IData &data)->bool" to "MyClass::func_t" exists

как это можно исправить?

Comment: `std::function<T>`?

Comment: @Павел Ериков, а как это выглядеть будет?

Comment: Ваш код [работает](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/j5Pa4f). Нужен [mcve].

Comment: хмм у меня лично ваш пример работает без ошибок)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, еще бы получить этот минимально воспроизводимый пример :(

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, разобрался - вечером с замыленными глазами забыл в лямбде указать что параметр константный

Comment: Тогда галочку лучше на свой ответ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
std::function<bool(const MyClass::IData&)>
```

Comment: Указатель на функцию имеет меньше оверхеда, и тоже должен работать. Если только ТС не дурит нас, и у его лямбды действительно пустой список захвата.

Comment: если `std::function<bool(const  MyClass::IData&)> filter`, то вылезает `Error (active) E0312 no suitable user-defined conversion from "type" to "std::function<bool (const MyClass::IData &)>" exists` когда вызываю как `load2list([](MyClass::IData& data) {return data.m_path >= 4; });`

Answer (score 1):

проблема оказалась до банального проста - в вызове в лямбда-выражении пропустил константный параметр и вместо

```
object.method([](const MyClass::IData& data) {return true;});
```

использовал

```
object.method([](MyClass::IData& data) {return true;});
```